# How to redirect through 'POST' method using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, post

I've queried and doesn't work out what I've found. Is there any way to redirect to give url with **POST** method using Javascript or jquery?

Comment: Can you put an example? I don't really understand the problem

Answer (score 63):

Based on [Eugene Naydenov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19064386/1414809)'s answer, I ended up using this which is able to fill form data also, hope to be useful for others:

```
function redirectPost(url, data) {
    var form = document.createElement('form');
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.method = 'post';
    form.action = url;
    for (var name in data) {
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = 'hidden';
        input.name = name;
        input.value = data[name];
        form.appendChild(input);
    }
    form.submit();
}

// redirectPost('http://www.example.com', { text: 'text\n\ntext' });
```

Update (2021): Some years later turned out a version that opens a new tab/window also would be useful for me so hopefully this would be useful also, just that make sure this will happen in a click event as browsers should block that otherwise,

```
function openPostPage(url, data) {
    var form = document.createElement('form');
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.target = '_blank';
    form.method = 'post';
    form.action = url;
    for (var name in data) {
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = 'hidden';
        input.name = name;
        input.value = data[name];
        form.appendChild(input);
    }
    form.submit();
    document.body.removeChild(form);
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer as it accounts for sending data via the POST method, which is why you would want to use a POST method redirection, or else you'd use GET.

Comment: You might have to add `document.body.appendChild(form);` to this (for example just before `form.submit()`), because the HTML spec doesn't allow forms that are not associated with the document to be submitted. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42081856) for more information.

Comment: I would suggest also adding `document.body.removeChild(form);` after the submit.

Comment: I'm glad I found this SO post and answer.  Using `XMLHttpRequest` to redirect a page from other domain wouldn't allow.  Browser will detect it with no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, this is one way to solve `CORS` issue using a form submit to redirect a post request.

Comment: @ruben056 We redirecting the currently displayed page away. Everything will be removed anyway.

Answer (score 19):

Create a form, fill `method` and `action` attributes, submit the form.

```
var redirect = function(url, method) {
    var form = document.createElement('form');
    form.method = method;
    form.action = url;
    form.submit();
};

redirect('http://www.example.com', 'post');
```

---

jQuery version (but I'd *prefer pure JavaScript* in this particular case):

```
var redirect = function(url, method) {
    $('<form>', {
        method: method,
        action: url
    }).submit();
};

redirect('http://www.example.com', 'post');
```

Comment: This won't work if the method is a different domain. However if you insert it into the document it will work.

Comment: Of course. Same as with any form submit. Just because of [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: I had to add this to let the submit works:  $('body').append(form);

Answer (score 10):

Here the idea is to send data to server while you redirect user to another webpage without using the GET method and maintaining a cosmetic appearance to your URL.
So we are going to use the same procedure of sending a Form with POST method.

HTML/Javascript code for creating the form and submitting it to server:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.method = 'post';
form.action = 'receive.php';
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = "text";
input.name = "data";
input.value = "this is the data I'm sending to server through POST";
form.appendChild(input);
form.submit();
</script>
<body>
<html>
```

Receiving this data in PHP:

```
<pre>
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
</pre>
```

In this way, users will be redirected to receive.php with some data being informed in a POST method.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is a trick. You create a hidden form and trigger the submit button, with jQuery for example:

```
<form method="POST" action="newurl.html" id="myform">
</form>
```

and do a

```
$('#myform').submit();
```

I suggest you to use the no-jQuery version posted by **Eugene Naydenov**

Comment: Note that this doesn't require jQuery if you change `$('#myform').submit()` to `document.querySelector('#myform').submit()`.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:**

```
var url = 'http://example.com/vote/' + Username;
var form = $('<form action="' + url + '" method="post">' +
  '<input type="text" name="api_url" value="' + Return_URL + '" />' +
  '</form>');
$('body').append(form);
$(form).submit();
```

Answer (score 2):

Redirect with POST vars (on jQuery)

```
var redirect = 'http://www.website.com/page?id=23231';
$.redirectPost(redirect, {x: 'example', y: 'abc'});

$.extend(
{
    redirectPost: function(location, args)
    {
        var form = '';
        $.each( args, function( key, value ) {
            form += '<input type="hidden" name="'+key+'" value="'+value+'">';
        });
        $('<form action="'+location+'" method="POST">'+form+'</form>').submit();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use serialize your form and all the data in post. Below is an example.

```
$("#submit_btn").click(function(){
        $('.error_status').html();
            if($("form#frm_message_board").valid())
            {
                $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "<?php echo site_url('message_board/add');?>",
                      data: $('#frm_message_board').serialize(),
                      success: function(msg) {
                          var msg = $.parseJSON(msg);
                          if(msg.success=='yes')
                          {
                                                                            return true;
                         }
                         else
                         {
                            alert('Server error');
                            return false;
                        }
                       }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: The question is how to redirect to a new page.  This will not redirect to a new page

Answer (score -3):

There  is no way to do so.

Even a `a`  element Sstrikes the `GET`.

What you can do is make a Ajax request  to post and in `on-success` use `window.open()`.

Answer (score -3):

I think you should construct and fill out a hidden method=POST action="YOUR_URL" form and submit it,

Answer (score -3):

Using jQuery post the data and redirect to your desired location like so:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'receivedata.asp',
  data: 'formValue=someValue',
  success: function(data){
      window.location = data;
  }
});
```

You could remove the data: 'formValue=someValue', if there is no data to pass to the page you want to post to.

Answer (score -4):

huh... use AJAX Jquery:

```
> $.ajax({
>                       type: "POST",
>                       url: "www.example.com/the_page_I_post_to.php",
>                       data: $('yourform').serialize(),//sent data
>                       success: function(msg) {
>                           alert("posted !");
>                        }
```

Comment: JQuery $.ajax does not actually redirect. It sends a XHR in the background. Answer posted by @Fernando works best according to what was asked.