# redirect through 'POST' - top.location.href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [redirect using javascript (similar to this page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19064352/how-to-redirect-through-post-method-using-javascript)  to redirect a click using POST so that variables will be hidden from the url. 
However the redirect is a standard `window.location.href`.
How can i redirect from within an iframe so that `top.location.href` is applied?

```
function postIt(url, data){

    $('body').append($('<form/>', {
        id: 'jQueryPostItForm',
        method: 'POST',
        action: url // << i cant control this to be top.location.href
    }));

    for(var i in data){
        $('#jQueryPostItForm').append($('<input/>', {
            type: 'hidden',
            name: i,
            value: data[i]
        }));
    }

    $('#jQueryPostItForm').submit();
};
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-target

Comment: @KevinB thanks! totally overlooked target