# Open Window.open() With POST Data and get data with PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I have form with username and password. when i click on submit buttom then username and password will pass to another page and open new window.

i know that i will pass this data by GET request like

```
window.open('url.php?unm=username&pass=password','_blank');
```

but in my case i don't want to display data in url. I want to use POST Method To get data in url.php page.

So How to do this. Please Help.. Thanks For Advance

Below Code I use :

```
$.post("url.php?unm=username&pass=password",function(data){
    $("#form").hide();
});
```

Comment: You should start with the manual on `$.post()`.

Comment: i know about $.post method.  In my case i must have to use $.post or $.ajax() required to use

Comment: why not put put them inside a form? form with action url.php and type post.

Comment: You should check what parameters it accepts.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do with form submit and then open new window

```
<form id="Form" method="post" action="url.php" target="TheWindow">
<input type="hidden" name="unm" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="pass" value="" />
</form>
<script>
function Post(name,password) {
  var f = document.getElementById('Form');
  f.unm.value = name;
  f.pass.value = password;
  window.open('', 'TheWindow');
  f.submit();
} 
Post("username","password");
</script>
```

Comment: The target may need to be `_new`, not sure it works this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by Javascript. See example below.[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19064352/how-to-redirect-through-post-method-using-javascript)

```
var redirect = function(url, method) {
    var form = document.createElement('form');
    form.method = method;
    form.action = url;
    form.submit();
};

redirect('http://www.example.com', 'post');
```

Comment: This will not pass the data to url.php file.

Comment: @SachinSanchaniya Might be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389646/send-post-data-on-redirect-with-javascript-jquery) can help

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="url.php" type="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="username" name="unm">
    <input type="hidden" value="password" name="pass">
    <button type="submit">
</form>
```

you can fetch the data from url.php like

$username = $_POST['unm'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button[name='loginBtn']").click(function(){
        $('#frm_RegisteredForm').attr('action','test.php');
        $('#frm_RegisteredForm').submit();
    });
});
</script>

<form name="frm_RegisteredForm" id="frm_RegisteredForm" action="javascript:void(0);" autocomplete="off" method="post"  target='_blank'>
    <input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" /> 
    <button type="button"  name="loginBtn" id="loginBtn" value="Add" accesskey="a">login</button>
</form>
```

Here I'm submitting my form from java script IE I'm using jQuery. To open new page I'm just specified the target of the form as blank in form tag it self. Try this. This will work for you too. This is working in my case.