# How to fix the error "Form submission canceled because the form is not connected" in the latest browser versions (IE, Mozilla and Chrome)

Tags: javascript, forms, form-submit

I had this piece of code perfectly running until a week back when chrome was updated to version 56. Now it does not work, When I checked the console I got the error `"Form submission canceled because the form is not connected"`. The submit function is not triggered when clicked. I'm new to coding so please help me with this issue.

```
function report_submit(){           
    var max = document.getElementById("totalCount").value;      
    var frm = document.createElement("form");

    frm.setAttribute("method", "POST");
    frm.setAttribute("action", "insertnew.php");
    frm.setAttribute("target", "selectnew.php");

    var hiddenField1 = document.createElement("input");
    hiddenField1.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    hiddenField1.setAttribute("name", "max");
    hiddenField1.setAttribute("value", max);
    frm.appendChild(hiddenField1);

    for (i = 0; i < max; i++) { 
        var date = "DATE" + i;
        var user = "USER" + i;
        var task_queue = "TASK_QUEUE" + i;
        var id_utter = "AUDIO" + i; 
        //var blueshift_link = "BLUESHIFT_LINK" + i;
        var overturned_fields = "OVERTURNED_FIELDS" + i;
        var id_error = "error_type" + i;
        var remarks = "remarks" + i;
        var completion_id = "COMPLETION_ID" + i;
        var ec_verifier = "EC_VERIFIER" + i;
        var ec_spoc = "EC_SPOC" + i;
        var manager = "MANAGER" + i;                        

        var date = document.getElementById(date).value;
        var user = document.getElementById(user).value;
        var task_queue = document.getElementById(task_queue).value; 
        var utterance_id = document.getElementById(id_utter).value;
        //var blueshift_link = document.getElementById(blueshift_link).value;
        var overturned_fields = document.getElementById(overturned_fields).value;
        var error_type = document.getElementById(id_error).value;
        var remarks = document.getElementById(remarks).value;
        var completion_id = document.getElementById(completion_id).value;
        var ec_verifier = document.getElementById(ec_verifier).value;
        var ec_spoc = document.getElementById(ec_spoc).value;
        var manager = document.getElementById(manager).value;

        alert(date);
        alert(user);
        alert(task_queue);
        alert(utterance_id);
        //alert(blueshift_link);
        alert(overturned_fields);
        alert(error_type);
        alert(remarks);
        alert(completion_id);
        alert(ec_verifier);
        alert(ec_spoc);     insert_function(frm,date,user,task_queue,utterance_id,overturned_fields,error_type,remarks,completion_id,ec_verifier,ec_spoc,manager,i);
    }

    frm.submit();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take some time to visit the [help] and also read [ask].  Questions of the form "here's my code, please debug it" are considered off-topic. StackOverflow is not a discussion, tutorial or debugging site.

Comment: grammar fixed and tag java removed

Comment: tag form-submit added

Answer (score 0):

Before you submit form data, you should make sure that your form has been added to document. Try to add this line before frm.submit():

document.body.appendChild(frm);

Also please reference to this answer: [Getting Error "Form submission canceled because the form is not connected"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42053775/getting-error-form-submission-canceled-because-the-form-is-not-connected)