# Form submission canceled because the form is not connected

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I have these html button:

```
<form ngNativeValidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #add_form="ngForm">
     <button class="btn btn-primary " type="submit[disabled]="!add_form.valid">ADD</button>
     <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="back()">Back</button>
</form>
```

And I obtain this warning in the console:

> Form submission canceled because the form is not connected

Anyone can help me to resolve this warning?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42531167/angular-2-form-submission-canceled-because-the-form-is-not-connected

Answer (score 13):

For your Back button, add `type="button"` to the declaration, like this:

```
<form ngNativeValidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #add_form="ngForm">
     <button class="btn btn-primary " type="submit[disabled]="!add_form.valid">ADD</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="back()">Back</button>
</form>
```

What's happening, is that Angular interprets the second button as another submit button, and so you're effectively navigating in the middle of a submit. That's why the messages tells you that form submission is being cancelled.

Comment: Cobus Kruger's answer should be marked as the correct answer.  Simply add  type="button" to remove the warning.