# Display data in a different angular component

Tags: angular, service, components, share

Could someone please give me a working example (or refer me to one) which illustrates this functionality in Angular:

Component A: gets data from a server (A user enters a word in an input field, the server responds with some definition)

Component B: the data received from the server will be displayed in this component.

I, for some reason, cannot get the data to display in another component than the one that fetched it from the server.

For more details: I posted the question here: [Angular: How to redirect into another page upon submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54450744/angular-how-to-redirect-into-another-page-upon-submit/54451481?noredirect=1#comment95751762_54451481)

I have a service to share the data between components, but my problem is how do I pass the data received from the server from Component A to Component B?

Comment: Take a look at the Angular documentation about component interaction https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#component-interaction. If the components have  a parent/child relationship, @Input() and @Output() can be used. If the components have a sibling relationship (they are in the same parent component), a service can be used to pass data between them. The documentation has examples of both methods.

Comment: I know I'm using a service: my question is how do I concretely pass the data from component A to component B and at the same time display the data in component B? I guess it's a sibling relationship here.

Comment: omar have you used EventEmitter before this??

Comment: Kashif, no I haven't used EventEmitter before but I'm going to follow the tutorial to get the basics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Angular documentation, data can be shared between components by using:

- [Pass data from parent to child with input binding](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding)
- [Parent listens for child event](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event)
- [Parent and children communicate via a service](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service)

The third example from the documentation shows communication between parent and child so here is an example of two sibling components sharing data via a service. [Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h7rltb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

First, set up the service with a `BehaviorSubject`. This allows components to push data to and get data from the service.

**data.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {of, BehaviorSubject, Observable} from 'rxjs'

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  private _data: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null)

  constructor() { }

  getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this._data.asObservable();
  }

  setData(data: any) {
    this._data.next(data);
  }

  getSomeData() {
    return of([
      {id: 1, name: 'Name 1'},
      {id: 2, name: 'Name 2'},
      {id: 3, name: 'Name 3'},
    ]);
  }

}
```

Next create a component, in this case `first.component`, that has the `DataService` injected into it. This component uses both methods of communication, `EventEmitter`s with `@Output()`s and setting data on the service for other components to subscribe to.

**first.component.ts**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';

import {DataService} from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-first',
  templateUrl: './first.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./first.component.css']
})
export class FirstComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() dataLoaded: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getSomeData().subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        // use this to emit data to a parent component
        this.dataLoaded.emit(data);

        // use this to set data in the service that other components can subscribe to
        this.dataService.setData(data);
      }
    );
  }

}
```

In the `AppComponent`, set up a variable `data` to hold the data that gets emitted from the `FirstComponent`.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  private _data: any[] = [];

  get data(): any[] {
    return this._data;
  }

  set data(data: any[]) {
    this._data = data;
  }
}
```

Then listen for the `dataLoaded` event in the app component template and set the app component's data.

**app.component.html**

```
<app-first (dataLoaded)="data = $event"></app-first>
```

To get data to the `SecondComponent`, when the `FirstComponent` subscribes to data and emits it to its parent component, the `FirstComponent` can also send that data back to the service which puts the data into another Observable that the `SecondComponent` can subscribe to.

**second.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import {DataService} from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-second',
  templateUrl: './second.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./second.component.css']
})
export class SecondComponent implements OnInit {
  data: any[] = [];

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe(
      (data: any) => this.data = data
    );
  }

}
```

The `SecondComponent` can now use the data loaded from the `FirstComponent` in its template.

**second.component.html**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of data">
      <td >{{ item?.id }}</td>
      <td >{{ item?.name }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi josavish, I will implement your solution and let you know of the results. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

import module.

```
import {EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
```

make an object

```
  @Output() arrayList = new EventEmitter();
```

emit your data from your first component

```
this.arrayList.emit(yourdata);
```

you need to write this line in other component of html file on top  (second component)

```
</app-header (arrayList)='displayChanges($event)'></app-header>
```

now make your function in secound component where you want to recieved yor data this
function call automatically when data emit from first component

```
displayChanges($firstComponentData){
  var yourData= firstComponentData;
  //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This are what services are for.

Services get instantiate one time and are never removed. When you insert them into an component via dependency injection you get always the same instance.

Think of it like a singleton.
You can save the data in a variable inside the service. Component A and B can access it and you are sure of that the accessed data are the same in both components.