# Error in Reactjs Form submission canceled because the form is not connected

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

***I'm making netflix clone using reactjs and firebase.I have login from firebase but when i'm trying to login through app,it is not routing to localhost:3000/profile.It stucks on login screen only***

**App.js file:**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import requests from './Requests';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Routes,Route}from"react-router-dom";
import LoginScreen from './screens/LoginScreen';
import { auth } from './firebase';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { login, logout, selectUser } from './features/userSlice';
import ProfileScreen from './screens/ProfileScreen';


function App() {
  const user = useSelector(selectUser);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((userAuth) => {
      if (userAuth) {
        dispatch(
          login({
            uid: userAuth.uid,
            email: userAuth.email,
        }))
      } else {
        dispatch(logout);
      }
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  },[dispatch]);
  
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Router>
        {!user ? (
          <LoginScreen />
        ): (
           <Routes>
              <Route path='/profile' element={<ProfileScreen />} />
              <Route exact path='/' element={<HomeScreen />} />
           </Routes>
        )}
       
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

   

export default App;
```

**SignupScreen.js file**

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { auth } from '../firebase';
import './SignupScreen.css';


function SignupScreen() {
  const emailRef = useRef(null);
  const passwordRef = useRef(null);


  const register = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
   
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      emailRef.current.value,
      passwordRef.current.value
    ).then((authUser) => {
        console.log(authUser);
    })
     .catch((error) => {
      alert(error.message);
     });
  };

  const signIn = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    

    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      emailRef.current.value,
      passwordRef.current.value

    ).then((authUser) => {
      console.log(authUser);
  })
    .catch((error) => {
      alert(error.message);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className='signupScreen'>
        <form>
            <h1>Sign In</h1>
            <input ref={emailRef} placeholder='email' type='email' autoComplete='off' />
            <input ref={passwordRef} placeholder='password' type='password' autoComplete='off' />
            <button type='submit' onClick={signIn}>Sign In</button>

            <h4>
              <span className="signupScreen__gray">New to Netflix? </span>
              <span className="signupScreen__link" onClick={register}> Sign Up now.</span>
              
            </h4>
        </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SignupScreen;
```

**ProfileScreen.js file**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { selectUser } from '../features/userSlice';
import { auth } from '../firebase';
import Nav from '../Nav';
import './ProfileScreen.css';

function ProfileScreen() {
  const user = useSelector(selectUser);
  return (
    <div className='profileScreen'>
        <Nav />
        <div className="profileScreen__body">
          <h1>Edit Profile</h1>
          <div className="profileScreen__info">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0b/Netflix-avatar.png" alt="netflix avatar" />

            <div className="profileScreen__details">
              <h2>{user.email}</h2>
              <div className="profileScreen__plans">
                <button
                  onClick={() => auth.signOut()}
                  className='profileScreen__signOut'>Sign Out</button>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default ProfileScreen;
```

*ERROR:* in console,it is showing

> Form submission canceled because the form is not connected

Comment: does this solve your issus https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42531167/angular-2-form-submission-canceled-because-the-form-is-not-connected