# html form submit cause "Form submission canceled because the form is not connected"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have the following HTML Form displayed, and I would like to call the javascript function sendMail() when the user clicks on the Send button:

```
<script type="text/template" id="compose-view-template">
<form id="email-compose" class="form-email-compose" method="get" action="javascript:sendMail();">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" id="input-to" placeholder="To" class="input-transparent form-control"
               value="<%= receiver %>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="input-subject" placeholder="Subject" class="input-transparent form-control"
               value="<%= subject %>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea rows="10" class="form-control" id="wysiwyg" placeholder="Message"><%- body %></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="btn-toolbar pull-xs-right">
            <button type="reset" id="compose-discard-button" class="btn btn-gray">Cancel</button>
            <button type="submit" id="compose-send-button" onclick="" class="btn btn-danger">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Send&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and the Javascript function:

```
function sendMail(){

console.log("submit new email");

}
</script>
```

but when I click on Send, I have the following error

> Form submission canceled because the form is not connected

even if I mention an action to the form or to the button onclick I still have the same error.
anybody knows how I can solve this issue ?

Comment: what does `method="get" action="javascript:sendMail();"` suppose to do?

Comment: to be honest I tried multiple ways to launch my Javascript function sendMail while clicking on Send Submit button, but either onSubmit or action doen't work, I still have the same error

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample of html page, which there is a button on it, and when u click on it, a javascrippt function shows up, and write a message on your page for you.

**Notice:**

To send a real email, you must make a backEnd code for it.

```js
                <script>
                    function sendRequest(){
                       console.log( "complete the function");
                       document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = "Email is sent!";
    
                    }
    
                  </script>
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
        <button type="button" onClick="sendRequest()" >Click me </button>
    
        <p id="data"> <p>

    </body>
    </html
```

Comment: yes it helps me but I still have the message Form submission canceled because the form is not connected...

Comment: yes, my js function is called but still get the error

Comment: could u please update ur question, so i would now ur current state. also please remove all ur comments from here, and i can ask more from u.

Comment: Also, please try these solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42053775/getting-error-form-submission-canceled-because-the-form-is-not-connected