# "Form submission canceled because the form is not connected"

Tags: javascript, html, dom

When the form was doing submit, It's showing this warning message.

The first method:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('actionBtn');
var form = document.getElementById('actionForm');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    btn.disabled = true;
    form.removeChild(btn);
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = 'start working!';
    form.submit();
});
```

The second method:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('actionBtn');

document.getElementById('actionForm').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    btn.disabled = true;
    this.removeChild(btn);
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML += 'start working!';
    this.submit();
});
```

they will be showing this message ("Form submission canceled because the form is not connected").

and this page html:

```
<form action="./patchPr18mToOesFeeFor189.jsp" method="GET" id="actionForm"> 

    <input type="hidden" name="start" value="start">
    <button id="actionBtn">Let's start</button>

</form>
```

Why is it so?

Comment: You can find a good explanation here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42053775/getting-error-form-submission-canceled-because-the-form-is-not-connected Good Luck!

Comment: @ZeeshanAdil Thanks! I found the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the following line:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML += 'start working!';
```