# How to make a non-ajax HTTP Post Request in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http

My question is very simple... How can make an Post [HttpRequest](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest) with params in angular 4. I could not find an example ... the examples I find are using HttpClient, but it's not what I need

Comment: what is wrong with HttpClient?

Comment: I need a non ajax post request... exactly a full  post request

Comment: @Igor what I need is to redirect the flow of my application to an external service to make the payment of a product .. the external service allows me to make payments for the different means of payment. for that reason I need a non-ajax post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect to an external URL in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338440/how-to-redirect-to-an-external-url-in-angular2). (`window.location.href = '...';`)

Comment: @Igor yes! I want to do a browser redirect

Comment: I mean if you are doing a browser redirect you can send it as query parameters if it isn't sensitive data. You would still use HttpClient...

Comment: @Igor I want to do a browser redirect, but with a post request

Comment: Possible duplicates of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8389646/1260204, https://stackoverflow.com/q/133925/1260204, https://stackoverflow.com/q/19064352/1260204

Comment: so, I would still suggest using a redirect with query params, not entirely sure if its possible to just redirect and post data, assuming this data is not sensitive

Comment: @PariBaker - `assuming this data is not sensitive` <= I am not sure what that has to do with anything?

Comment: Seems like a much easier solution for a redirect. He would be able to just pass his query Params through the router as an object. No?

Answer (score 0):

Without [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) (aka AJAX), you're not able to instruct the browser to make an HTTP POST request. By navigating to some URL, the browser makes a HTTP GET request.

If you want to send an HTTP POST request directly from the browser, you'll need to use XHR/fetch.

Comment: `fetch` is an option, though.

Comment: @jhpratt Yes, but `fetch` uses XHR under the hood.

Comment: Does it? I was under the impression that it is a separate thing entirely (though polyfills would certainly use it). Regardless, this is semantics.

Comment: @jhpratt, Actually I think you're right. They may be two separate things.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah How I can use XHR/fetch in angular 4?

Comment: @AlejoDev It's already been [shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52823170/1911755). Here are the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/http)

Answer (score 0):

Circling back to this, although I managed to create a test with a get method using the HttpRequest class I was having trouble with using the POST method. Instead I used the HttpModule from @angular/http and the accompanying classes. Then I tried adding an e.preventDefault. Try that and see if it works for you. Additionally you may need to use pure JS methods here.

in AppComonent

```js
import {Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers, Request, RequestMethod} from '@angular/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

export class AppComonent implements OnInit {

dataBody =JSON.stringify({
    title: "foo",
    body: "bar",
    userId: 1
  });

  headers;
  requestOptions;
  requestMethod;
  Response;


  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  ngOnInit(
  ) {


  }
onPreventDefault(e){
  e.preventDefault();
}
onPostData(){
  return this.postRequest('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', this.dataBody);
}

 postRequest(url,data) {
    this.headers = new Headers();
    this.headers.append("Content-Type", 'application/json');

    this.requestOptions = new RequestOptions({
        method: RequestMethod.Post,
        url: url,
        headers: this.headers,
        body: data
    });

    return this.http.request(new Request(this.requestOptions))
        .subscribe((res: Response) => {
            if (res) {
              console.log(res);

            }
        });
}


}
```

in module.ts

```js
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

imports: [HttpModule];
```

in app-component.html

```html
 <form (ngSubmit)="onPostData()" (submit)="onPreventDefault($event)" target="_blank" action="http://localhost:3000/api/users" >
  <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

in `app.module.ts`

```
import { HttpClientModule } '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule ({
imports: [HttpClientModule]
})
```

in app.component.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export class AppComponent {
   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.http.post('http://someurl/endpoint', {postData1: 'avb', postdat2: 'xyx}).subscribe(res => console.log(res), error => console.log(error));
   }
```

}

Comment: Author asks about providing params in post request, beside that it's in ``HttpClient`` you didn't answer question.